# React: How to send information to the parent component?

Tags: coffeescript, functional-programming, reactjs

I've created a pretty simple Navigation View Controller, modeled after the concept of the iOS UINavigationController. It basically just maintains a history of routes, and animates a push to another route or a pop.

(I hope you dont mind the coffeescript ;)

```
createView = (spec) -> React.createFactory(React.createClass(spec))
{div, span, input, img, button} = React.DOM
cond = (condition, result, otherwise) -> if condition then result?() else otherwise?()
Transition = React.createFactory(React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup)

NavVC = createView
  displayName: 'NavVC'
  mixins: [React.addons.PureRenderMixin]
  propTypes:
    rootScene: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    renderScene: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  getInitialState: ->
    transition: 'navvc-appear'
    stack: [@props.rootScene]
  push: (route) ->
    @setState
      stack: React.addons.update(@state.stack, {$push: [route]})
      transition: 'navvc-push'
  pop: ->
    if @state.stack.length is 1
      console.warn("You shouldn't pop off the root view of a NavVC!")
    else
      @setState
        stack:  React.addons.update(@state.stack, {
          $splice:[[@state.stack.length - 1, 1]]
        })
        transition: 'navvc-pop'
  popFront: ->
    @setState
      stack: [@state.stack[0]]
      transition: 'navvc-pop'
  render: ->
    route = @state.stack[@state.stack.length - 1]
    pop = @pop if @state.stack.length > 1
    popFront = @popFront if @state.stack.length > 1
    div
      className: 'navvc'
      Transition
        transitionName: @state.transition
        @props.renderScene(route, @push, pop, popFront)
```

This works quite well and as expected. Here's a simple example of a page that recursively pushes and pops using the NavVC.

```
Page = createView
  displayName: 'Page'
  mixins: [React.addons.PureRenderMixin]
  propTypes:
    title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    push: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    pop: React.PropTypes.func
  push: ->
    @props.push(Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,100))
  render: ->
    div
      className: 'page'
      div
        className: 'title'
        onClick: @push
        @props.title
      cond @props.pop,
        => div
          className: 'back'
          onClick: @props.pop
          "< BACK"

App = createView
  renderScene: (route, push, pop, popFront) ->
    Page
      key: route
      title: route
      pop: pop
      push: push
  render: ->
    NavVC
      rootScene: 'Hello NavVC'
      renderScene: @renderScene


React.render App(), document.body
```

And here it is in action in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccorcos/4gvtwsr9/).

---

Now here's my problem. This works great when the child component is doing the pushing and popping. But what if a parent or sibling component is doing the pushing or popping?

Suppose the page itself is entirely unaware of the NavVC:

```
Page = createView
  displayName: 'Page'
  mixins: [React.addons.PureRenderMixin]
  propTypes:
    title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  render: ->
    div
      className: 'page'
      div
        className: 'title'
        @props.title
```

And suppose we have some buttons that are siblings/parents of the NavVC which do the pushing and popping for us.

```
App = createView
  getInitialState: -> {}
  renderScene: (route, push, pop, popFront) ->
    @setState({push, pop})
    Page
      key: route
      title: route
  push: ->
    @state.push?(Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,100))
  render: ->
    div
      className: 'app'
      NavVC
        rootScene: 'Hello NavVC'
        renderScene: @renderScene
      cond @state.pop,
        => div
          className: 'left'
          onClick: @state.pop
          '<'
      div
        className: 'right'
        onClick: @push
        '>'

React.render App(), document.body
```

Well this is going to give us an error as it should.

> Invariant Violation: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

When App renders, NavVC is going to call renderScene which is going to call setState which requires an immediate re-render all over again. Currently the only solution I've come up with is to defer the setState until after the render cycle:

```
    window.setTimeout => 
      @setState({push, pop})
    , 0
```

You can check out a working version of this example in the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccorcos/mtqh79ea/).

But this solution seems wrong in some very fundamental ways. Its not declarative, it involves two renders every single time, and it breaks the one-directional data flow pattern. I desperately want to use this same component for both use cases -- the child pushes and pops, or the parent/sibling pushes and pops, or maybe a hybrid where the child pushes and the parent pops. I just can't seem to come up with a functional pattern that accomplishes this without breaking some very fundamental rules of good programming.

---

EDIT 1:

So I think I've figured out a step in the right direction: EventEmitters. The buttons emit events, and the NavVC listens to those events. We can wire up these events through the App component and the NavVC will listen for those events on mount and unregister those listeners on unmount. This maintains one-directional data flow!

One problem still remains though. The NavVC needs to be able to tell the back button if it is poppable so the back button knows whether or not it can be displayed... I haven't figured this out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. This was a huge pain, but I figured out a solution that is satisfactory -- I'd love some input though.

I created this idea of a Proxy component that fits in some space which can be controlled by a parent or a sibling.

```
App = createView
  componentWillMount: ->
    @PushProxy = createProxy(@renderPush)
    @PopProxy = createProxy(@renderPop)
  renderPush: (push) ->
    div
      className: 'right'
      onClick: -> push(Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,100))
      '>'
  renderPop: (pop) ->
    cond pop,
      => div
        className: 'left'
        onClick: pop
        '<'
  renderScene: (route, push, pop, popFront) ->
    Page
      key: route
      title: route
  render: ->
    console.log "render app"
    div
      className: 'app'
      @PushProxy()
      @PopProxy()
      NavVC
        rootScene: 'Hello NavVC'
        renderScene: @renderScene
        pushProxy: @PushProxy
        popProxy: @PopProxy
```

These Proxy components are rendered to from other components in their render function.

```
NavVC = createView
  # clip
  render: ->
    console.log "render navvc"
    route = @state.stack[@state.stack.length - 1]
    pop = @pop if @state.stack.length > 1
    popFront = @popFront if @state.stack.length > 1
    @props.pushProxy.dispatch(@push)
    @props.popProxy.dispatch(pop)
    div
      className: 'navvc'
      Transition
        transitionName: @state.transition
        @props.renderScene(route, @push, pop, popFront)
```

This method still requires a setTimeout of zero, but its optimized not to render more than necessary so I think I'm alright with it.

```
rememberLast = (f) ->
  lastArg = (->)
  lastResult = false
  (arg) ->
    if lastArg isnt arg
      lastResult = f(arg)
    lastArg = arg
    return lastResult

defer = (f) ->
  (arg) ->
      window.setTimeout ->
        f(arg)
      , 0

createProxy = (renderComponent) ->  
  value = undefined
  listeners = {}
  listen = (f) ->
    id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,100)
    listeners[id] = f
    if value isnt undefined then f(value)
    {stop: -> delete listeners[id]}
  dispatch = (x) ->
    value = x
    for id, f of listeners
      f(x)

  Proxy = createView
    displayName: 'Proxy'
    getInitialState: ->
      value: undefined
    componentWillMount: ->
      @listener = listen (value) =>
        @setState({value})
    componentWillUnMount: ->
      @listener.stop()
    render: ->
      if @state.value isnt undefined
        console.log "proxy render"
        renderComponent(@state.value)
      else
        false

  Proxy.dispatch = rememberLast defer dispatch
  return Proxy
```

Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccorcos/omwqpegx/) demonstrating it in action and check out the log statements to see that its rendering optimally.

I'm curious to hear from someone React people if this is proper thought. Maybe there is a more principled way of doing this.